# "from" is not recognized as an internal command

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

Getting an error from Google Cloud SDK on Windows 10:

"from" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I've already tried to add path to:
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk.staging\bin
and
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin
to my system path, but that don't solved the issue.

Comment: Hi Richard, can you be more specific?  Please describe, what was that you was trying to achieve. What was the exact command that you introduced. Please include you error trace, complete one, to investigate on the issue.

Comment: Hi, @Pawel Czuczwara. I'm trying to use urlfetch command: `from google.appengine.api import urlfetch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i understand you are using:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
```

As a CLI command, while this is a Python instruction. Hence, the error you are facing.

Please note that the correct approach would be:

1. Install the package:

   ```
   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
   ```
2. Import the module from within your Python code:

   ```
   from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
   ```
3. Use the functionalities of the module depending on your use case.

With that said you should also have in mind that:

- You can also issue an outbound HTTP request using the standard Python libs: urllib, urllib2, or httplib. For more information about it go [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests).
- The [URL Fetch service is not available in the flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#url_fetch) environment. However, there are no sandbox restrictions, so your app can use any HTTP library to get URL Fetch functionality.